# how to use jquery variable in inline css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have an script that i want to generate i div where ever user clicks and that div stays there so now i have this jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').click(function(e) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        $('#x_axis').html(e.clientX - offset.left);
        var x = (e.clientX - offset.left);
        $('#y_axis').html(e.clientY - offset.top);
        var y = (e.clientY - offset.top);
        $('body').append('<div id="bloom" style="position: relative; left: HERE I WANT TO PLACE X;">asd</div>');
        $('#bloom').css('left', x);
        $('#bloom').css('top', y);
    });
});
```

now on this line i want to add my X and Y variables to left and top attribute :

```
            $('body').append('<div id="bloom" style="position: relative; left: HERE I WANT TO PLACE X;">asd</div>');
```

any idea how this can be done ?? or any better way to make this thing that when user click on each part of page a div generates there

Comment: Three (edit: four) answers, and none of them do it properly. `$('body').append($('<div>').attr('id', "bloom").css({ position: "relative", left: x }).text("asd"));`

Comment: Also note that you don't want to "use jquery variable in inline css", what you want to do is "insert a variable into a string", a problem which is much easier to solve via Google. You need to cut irrelevant stuff from your problem before plugging it into a search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly place by adjusting the `''`

```
$('body').append('<div id="bloom" style="position: relative; left:'+x+';">asd</div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use template literals for that

**Solution**

```
  $('body').append(`<div id="bloom" style="position: relative; left: ${x};">asd</div>`);
```

[More about template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: should i add any thing to my project because thats not working it just out puts ${x} in html

Comment: use `` instead of '' for the enclosure,

Answer (score 1):

you can concatenate the variable

eg:

```
 $('body').append('<div id="bloom" style="position: relative; left:' + x + ';">asd</div>');
```

or

use template literals

```
$('body').append(`<div id="bloom" style="position: relative; left:${x};">asd</div>`);
```

Comment: should i add any thing to my project because thats not working it just out puts ${x} in html

Answer (score 1):

You can concat the javascript variable in this format:

```
 $('body').append('<div id="bloom" style="position: relative; left:' + x + ';">asd</div>');
```